# Is thermodynamic steady state unique?

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations, steady-state

As an introduction to my question imagine a homogeneous 3D heat conducting body (under constant pressure) subject to Fourier's law. In steady state it satisfies
$$\nabla (\kappa \nabla T) = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where in $\kappa = \kappa(T)$ I explicitly assume a non-trivial dependence of the heat conduction coefficient on the local temperature. Assume that at certain surface patches of the body we prescribe the temperature, $T_1, T_2, ..$, while the rest is insulated, $\frac{\partial T}{\partial n}=0$. The non-linear dependence of the conductivity on the local temperature results in a non-linear partial differential equation for $T$.

Now the so-called Kirchhoff transformation $\theta (T) = \frac{1}{\kappa_0}\int_0^T\kappa (u)du$, or $\frac{d\theta}{dT}=\frac{\kappa}{\kappa_0}$, where $\kappa_0$ is a conveniently chosen scaling constant, will transform $\eqref{1}$ into a *linear* partial differential equation for $\theta$,
$$\nabla^2\theta = 0 \tag{2}\label{2}$$
The boundary conditions will also transform to constants for the $k^{th}$ patch as fixed at $\theta(T_k)$ the rest being insulated per $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial n}=0$.

This way we have the *linear* Laplace equation with mixed boundary conditions that has a unique solution and, more importantly, Kirchhoff's transformation assures that despite being nonlinear the corresponding solution of $\eqref{1}$ is also unique.

The uniqueness conclusion has the interesting consequence that, at least in steady state, it does not matter in which *order* we set up the boundary temperatures in an actual experiment, asymptotically, it should lead to the same temperature distribution.

This is for background. Now moving from pure heat conduction to a more general case, take a thermodynamic system that satisfies the so-called local equilibrium condition, that is locally in any sufficiently small volume it satisfies the Gibbs equation $du = Tds +\sum_k Y_kdX_k$, where $du$ is the internal energy, and $X_k,Y_k$ are the local extensive and conjugate intensive variables.

Subject this system to constant external "reservoirs", that is prescribe the intensive parameters at certain patches of the boundary surface and at other patches the flow rates of the extensives may be given. For example, at some patches the temperature while at others, say, the electric or chemical potentials, or the electric currents are given, etc.

My question: what thermodynamic principle will guarantee that in such a strongly nonlinear system, the steady state distribution will depend only on the values of the *prescribed* intensives or fluxes and not on the order as they are introduced?